# Azure Video Upload Task is getting failed @"My PlayReady Task" Error: MediaProcessor : An exception occurred during the execution of the task

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

i am using the below code to apply DRM to my video file. But the task is getting failed, What should i do to get this working?

I can see "My PlayReady Task" goes to 100 % and suddenly throws an error.

ERROR DETAILS:
My PlayReady Task
MediaProcessor : An exception occurred during the execution of the task

Few days back it was working. Not sure what happened now?

```
********************Code sample *************************************************
private static IJob EncodeToAdaptiveBitrateAndConvertToSmoothAndProtect(string inputMediaFilePath, string configFilePath)
        {
            // Create asset and upload file
            IAsset asset = CreateAssestAndUploadSingleFile(AssetCreationOptions.None, inputMediaFilePath);

            // Create a new Job
            IJob job = mediaContext.Jobs.Create("Encode to multi-bitrate and convert to smooth job");


            // Create a new task to encode to Adaptive Bitrate 

            // Get a reference to the Windows Azure Media Encoder
            IMediaProcessor encoder = GetLatestMediaProcessorByName("Windows Azure Media Encoder");

            ITask adpativeBitrateTask = job.Tasks.AddNew("MP4 to Adaptive Bitrate Task",
               encoder,
               "H264 Adaptive Bitrate MP4 Set 720p",
               TaskOptions.None);

            // Specify the input Asset
            adpativeBitrateTask.InputAssets.Add(asset);

            // Add a new output Asset
            IAsset abrAsset = adpativeBitrateTask.OutputAssets.AddNew("Adaptive Bitrate Asset", AssetCreationOptions.None);


            // Create a new task to convert the Adaptive Bitrate Asset to a Smooth Streaming Asset

            // Get a reference to the Windows Azure Media Packager
            IMediaProcessor packager = GetLatestMediaProcessorByName("Windows Azure Media Packager");

            // Windows Azure Media Packager does not accept string presets, so load xml configuration
            string smoothConfig = File.ReadAllText(configFilePath);

            // Create a new Task to convert adaptive bitrate to Smooth Streaming
            ITask smoothStreamingTask = job.Tasks.AddNew("Adaptive Bitrate to Smooth Task",
               packager,
               smoothConfig,
               TaskOptions.None);

            // Specify the input Asset, which is the output Asset from the first task
            smoothStreamingTask.InputAssets.Add(abrAsset);

            // Add a new output Asset
            IAsset smoothOutputAsset = smoothStreamingTask.OutputAssets.AddNew("Smooth Asset", AssetCreationOptions.None);

            // Set up the third task to protect the Adaptive Bitrate Smooth Streaming Asset with PlayReady. 

            // Get a media encryptor reference
            IMediaProcessor playreadyProcessor = GetLatestMediaProcessorByName("Windows Azure Media Encryptor");

            // Read the configuration XML
            string configPlayReady = File.ReadAllText(configFilePathPlayReady);

            // Create a third task. 
            ITask playreadyTask = job.Tasks.AddNew("My PlayReady Task",
               playreadyProcessor,
               configPlayReady,
               TaskOptions.ProtectedConfiguration);

            // Add the input asset, which is the smooth streaming output asset from the second task. 
            playreadyTask.InputAssets.Add(smoothOutputAsset);

            // Add an output asset to contain the results of the job.
            playreadyTask.OutputAssets.AddNew("PlayReady protected output asset", AssetCreationOptions.None);

            // Use the following event handler to check job progress.  
            job.StateChanged += new EventHandler<JobStateChangedEventArgs>(StateChanged);

            // Launch the job.
            job.Submit();

            // Optionally log job details. 
            LogJobDetails(job.Id);

            // Check job execution and wait for job to finish. 
            Task progressJobTask = job.GetExecutionProgressTask(CancellationToken.None);
            progressJobTask.Wait();

            // Get a refreshed job reference after waiting on a thread.
            job = GetJob(job.Id);

            // Check for error
            if (job.State == JobState.Error)
            {
                 Console.WriteLine("\nExiting method due to job error.");
            }
            return job;

        }
```

Comment: are you using same media files which were working few weeks ago, or new media files? Try with media files that used to work.

Comment: I am using the same media file.. and it was working fine from Azure -- http://prashanthtest.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/925e4aaa-003a-45e4-a872-9a63a42fd116/dizzy.ism/Manifest

Comment: Even Now the smooth streaming URL is working fine, only the Playready part is getting failed after reaching 100%

Answer (score 0):

What playready license server are you using ? 
From code perspective everything seems to be looking good. Since playready protection preset has not be included in sample, i assume it looks similar to example in following article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn189154.aspx
Please make sure that value in licenseAquisitionURL is accessible from public network and your keySeedValue, or a keyID and a contentKey are still valid.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a jobID that you can share from the instance that this failed?